# easy_localization - using new line - \n in a String

Tags: flutter, flutter-easy-localization

In my Flutter Project I'm using the package easy_localization (https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization).

I want to use Strings like this: `This is my Test String.\nIt is supposed to be separated by a new line!`.

easy_localization is ignoring the \n and simply shows it as the characters \n and not doing a real new line. A flutter string usually knows what is meant by a \n and interpret it correct.

How do I archive that a \n still get's interpreted as a new line?

**Edit:**

My localization files are xml files that are kinda like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
      <my_string_key>This is my Test String.\nIt is ... by a new line!</my_string_key>
</root>
```

And I call it somewhere as `tr("my_string_key")`

**Edit:**

My Solution now is just that I created a file my_localizer.dart that only got this function:

`String myTr(String key) { return tr(key).replaceAll("\\n", "\n"); }`

I could import it at the files that I needed it and can use it exactly like the original tr():

`myTr("my_string_key")`